# Python - Writing from a file to two files

Tags: python, file, function, if-statement

I wish to have a function that takes in a input file and outputs 2 files. The first output file I have done but the second output file will depend on the results of the first which I cannot get working...

Input file:

```
FirstName,LastName,DOB,POSTCODE
FirstName,LastName,DOB,POSTCODE
FirstName,LastName,DOB,POSTCODE
```

Output file 1:

```
Firstname,DOB
Firstname,DOB
Firstname,DOB
```

Outputfile 2: (ONLY IF DOB equals 2000)

```
Firstname,POSTCODE
Firstname,POSTCODE
Firstname,POSTCODE
```

I have functions that do this task perfectly well but now I wish to further the function for my learning benefits and have become stuck...

What I want to happen...

IF the DOB in output file 1 is '2000', then write to output file 3.

Current function:

```
def func(iFile):
    with open(iFile) as iF:
        with open("DOB.txt", "a") as oF1:
            for line in iF:
                chars = line.split(',')
                oF1.write(chars[0] + ',' + chars[2])
                oF1.write('\n')
        with open("DOB.txt", "a") as iF1:
            with open("POSTCODE.txt", "a") as oF2:
                chars = line.split(',')
                for line in iF:
                    if char[2] == "2000":
                        oF2.write(chars[0] + ',' + chars[3])
                        oF2.write('\n')
```

So based on this....

I want the input file into the function first split into one file with the firstname & DOB, then for each line within that file, if the DOB of that file is '2000', i want that output in a new firstname.POSTCODE file.

My current script creates both files.
The DOB.txt file is populated but makes duplicate lines.
The POSTCODE.txt file is empty.

Any help will be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open both output files before iterating over lines in `iF` (that's why your version didn't produce any `POSTCODE.txt` - because the `iF` was already iterated over and there was no lines left).

This should work:

```
def func(iFile):
    with open(iFile) as iF:
        with open("DOB.txt", "a") as oF1:
            with open("POSTCODE.txt", "a") as oF2:
                for line in iF:
                    chars = line.split(',')
                    oF1.write(chars[0] + ',' + chars[2])
                    oF1.write('\n')
                    if chars[2] == "2000":
                        oF2.write(chars[0] + ',' + chars[3])
                        oF2.write('\n')
```

Comment: Thanks - it works but there is one issue - it creates multiple 'Firstname:DOB' in output file 1?

Answer (score 1):

So you have this input:

```
FirstName,LastName,DOB,POSTCODE
FirstName,LastName,2000,POSTCODE
FirstName,LastName,DOB,POSTCODE
FirstName,LastName,DOB,POSTCODE
FirstName,LastName,2000,POSTCODE
FirstName,LastName,DOB,POSTCODE
```

You want this output 1:

```
FirstName,DOB
FirstName,DOB
FirstName,DOB
FirstName,DOB
```

And this putput 2:

```
FirstName,POSTCODE
FirstName,POSTCODE
```

Then you can try simply this:

```
with open('input.txt') as input, open('output1.txt', 'w') as oF1, open('output2.txt', 'w') as oF2 :

    for line in input:
        chars = line.split(',')

        if chars[2] == "2000":
            oF2.write(chars[0] + "," + chars[3])
        else:
            oF1.write(chars[0] + "," + chars[2] + "\n")
```

Comment: Output file 1 is empty; however output file 2 has worked

Comment: @nouseforname that's because you probably had different data, so you didn't see that you should ALLWAYS write to `oF1`, but your code chooses only one output file - either `oF1` or `oF2`, but Eric1989 wanted to allways write to `oF1` and sometimes also to `oF2`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this technique is somewhat deprecated, but you could just do:

```
file1 = open("firstfile.txt","w")
file2 = open("secondfile.txt","w")
```

and then use `file1.write(...)` and `file2.write(...)` to split the output correctly. The `with` syntax might be a bit tricky in this sort of context.

Also, `"a"` is for append. Be careful that you don't use `"a"` when you mean `"w"` and vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try this. Can you give a an example of code relating to my current function of where to place the basics such as the IF statements and the opening of which files where. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the DOB.txt the second time as `open("DOB.txt", "a")` which is meant for appending, not for reading.

No surprise on the empty POSTCODE.txt since you won't be able to read it when you open it the second time.

Comment: Hi - I know this is the case, but I tried putting into into the first opening of the file but I had no luck and I'm just resorting to anything now to try to get it working

Comment: Use `open("DOB.txt", "r")` the `second` time and leave the first one as is.

Comment: It is still producing the same problems - it's just the positioning of the if statement I think as to why its not writing to the postcode file -

Comment: add print statements, this should be trivial to debug